# Why isn't Random class static?

Tags: java, random

In Java we have static class Math. You don't need to create its objects so its static. Another one is Random class. We don't need to create its instances so why isn't it static too? My classes I often use random numbes and get mad when have to create field rand in every class to generate random numbers. So why isn't it static?

Comment: Um, top-level classes in Java can't be declared as static, and you *do* need to create instances of `Random`. Both of the premises of your question are incorrect, basically.

Comment: There is a static random() in Math.

Comment: A better question would have been: "why isn't the `Random` class `final`?"

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The Random class has state, including where it is in its sequence, as the values produced are not truly random, just a pseudo-random sequence.

This can be demonstrated by initialising two instances with the same seed.

```
Random a = new Random(123);
Random b = new Random(123);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    System.out.println(a.nextInt() + "," + b.nextInt());
}
```

Output

```
-1188957731,-1188957731
1018954901,1018954901
-39088943,-39088943
1295249578,1295249578
1087885590,1087885590
```

If you create with the default constructor Random(), then the seed is initialized based on the current time in nanoseconds + a static counter, which means different instances are very likely to have different sequences.

Comment: *If you create with the default constructor Random(), then the seed is initialized with the current time in milliseconds* -- this is incorrect, the seeding even for the default `new Random()` is more sophisticated than just `System.currentTimeMillis()`

Comment: @bestsss Apologies, you are correct. I was looking at some very old source for java.util.Random (one of the first matches on google annoyingly). Using System.currentTimeMillis() used to be the behaviour pre 1.5, but now as you say, much more sophisticated.

Comment: Yes, it was changed in 1.5, it was indeed millisec only (quite lame)

Answer (score 14):

You **do** need to create instances, because a random-number generator has **state**.  Specifically, state that controls the current position in the pseudo-random sequence.

If you want multiple independent generators (that don't share state), then you need separate instances.

Answer (score 5):

The reason is that you may require several independent random number generators. This is achieved by having several instances of `Random`.

Answer (score 5):

It's all about seeds. As you know we don't talk about real random numbers but pseudo-random. When you know the first number you can calculate the others. This is why we use somethig what is called 'a seed'. Each object of `Random` has different seed. If `Random` would be static you couldn't have two different seeds. Note that `setSeed()` method would then affect all random numbers generators (and we often want to change only one).